# Responders gem: add a model's base errors to the flash message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, responders

Is there an easy way to add a model's base errors to the flash message in the [responders](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders/) gem?

When I try to delete a record with depending children that has `dependent: :restrict_with_error` set, then I see an error like "X could not be destroyed", but nothing more.

Inspecting the record, I see that there is an additional error added to `base`:

```
@messages={:base=>["Cannot delete record because dependent children exist"]}, @details={:base=>[{:error=>:"restrict_dependent_destroy.has_many", :record=>"children"}]
```

Is there an easy way to append base errors to the flash message?

Answer (score 0):

You use following code in order to display flash errors message

```
if object.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Success Message"
elsif object.errors.messages[:base].present?
    flash[:error] = object.errors.messages[:base]
else
    flash[:error] = 'Object Not Destroyed'
end
```

and write following code on view to display flash message

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have stated more clearly that I'm asking for a way to do this automatically using the FlashResponder (responders gem).